# enabling/disabling Crashlytics at runtime in iOS app

Tags: ios, crashlytics, firebase-analytics, disable

Can't seem to enable/disable Crashlytics at runtime by a method call in swift - my app is setup with firebase analytics and Crashlytics for firebase - the following call (per the [Google dev website](https://firebase.google.com/docs/crash/disable-sdk)) gives me "**Use of unresolved identifier 'Crash'**" even when importing crashlytics and firebase

```
Crash.sharedInstance().crashCollectionEnabled = false
```

Comment: Are you using Fabric or Crashlytics? Pod / binary? Latest version?

Comment: Appears as if your Crashlytics is not imported. It could also be an issue of dynamic framework usage as these are not loaded until usage. Usage of a static lib cab be better in such scenarios

Comment: I added Firebase analytics to the project, followed by crashlytics per the firebase instructions on google's website. It's the latest version of Firebase and Crashlytics. What import am I missing?

Answer (score 9):

In new SDK you can do it as per [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/customize-crash-reports?platform=ios#enable-reporting):

> By default, Crashlytics automatically collects crash reports for all
> your app's users. To give users more control over the data they send,
> you can enable opt-in reporting for your users by disabling automatic
> collection and initializing Crashlytics only for selected users:
>
> Turn off automatic collection by adding a new key to your Info.plist
> file:

```
Key: FirebaseCrashlyticsCollectionEnabled 
Value: false
```

> Enable collection for select users by calling the Crashlytics data collection
> override at runtime. The override value persists across launches of
> your app so Crashlytics can automatically collect reports for future
> launches of that app instance. To opt out of automatic crash
> reporting, pass false as the override value.

```
 Crashlytics.crashlytics().setCrashlyticsCollectionEnabled(true)
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the Firebase framework that provided that method has been deprecated.

You should now be using the Crashlytics way: https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/customize-crash-reports#enable_opt-in_reporting