# How to disable crash reporting in while app is in background state in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, crashlytics

Firebase crashlytics is integrated into my application and working fine.
I am experiencing crashes while the app is in the background and I wanted to disable these crash reporting but other crashes must be reported.

Answer (score 1):

Follow the instructions from:

[enabling/disabling Crashlytics at runtime in iOS app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56421527/enabling-disabling-crashlytics-at-runtime-in-ios-app)

Add this key value to your info.plist:

```
Key: FirebaseCrashlyticsCollectionEnabled 
Value: false
```

You can then manually enable or disable crash reporting by using this method:

```
 Crashlytics.crashlytics().setCrashlyticsCollectionEnabled(true)
```

So now you can enable Crashlytics when the app is launched, disable it when *applicationDidEnterBackground* is triggered and re-enable it when *applicationWillEnterForeground* is trigerred.

Comment: Did you implement likewise? Is it hampering crash reporting?

Comment: No I didn't. My answer is theoretical.